# Cmake can't find -lboost_system

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-asio

I am trying to compile a C++ program on my linux VM. This program is using `boost asio`. Here is how the `CMakeLists.txt` looks like :

```
project(server_c++) 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR D:\\Sources\\server_c++\\build)

message(STATUS "start running cmake...")
    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "/u/refdev64/boost/v1.66.0/include/")
    set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "/u/refdev64/boost/v1.66.0/")
    FIND_PACKAGE(Boost)

if (Boost_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
    ADD_DEFINITIONS( "-DHAS_BOOST" )
endif()

add_executable(Server src/main.cpp src/TcpServer.cpp include/TcpServer.h src/Server.cpp include/Server.h include/ServerParameters.h include/StreamParameters.h include/Message.h src/MessageHandler.cpp include/MessageHandler.h src/Channel_setup.cpp include/Channel_setup.h)
set_property(TARGET Server PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 11)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
target_link_libraries(Server boost_system)
```

Unfortunatly, when launching `cmake CMakeLists.txt`, I get the following error :

```
-- start running cmake...
-- Boost version: 1.66.0
-- Boost version: 1.66.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /root/Documents
Linking CXX executable Server
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[2]: *** [Server] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Server.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

Since all directories are right, and cmake finds `boost`, I don't get what I am doing wrong. Am I missing anything in `CMakeLists.txt`?

Cmake version is : 2.8.12.2
g++ version is : 5.1.0.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ...)` - **Never set** `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` variable. Treat is as *readonly*. If you want to manage output artifacts locations, CMake provide other means for that.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Just a quick guess, but your cmake version is quite outdated, while the boost version is rather recent. Have you tried with a newer cmake version? Then, the boost targets are also exported as `Boost::system`.

Comment: @lubgr, I thought about this as well. Unfortunatly, this VM is own by the company I work for, and I don't have rights to upgrade or install anything. I am leaving soon, and an update request might take a long time to be answered.

Comment: You can download a newer cmake version locally somewhere in your home directory and add the `bin` directory to your `$PATH` env. variable (at the beginning). No need to install cmake system-wide.

Comment: @lubgr, didn't think about that. I just did it, and I am unfortunatly still getting the same error

Comment: You could try deleting the two lines before `find_package(boost)` and instead pass `-D BOOST_ROOT=...`?!

Comment: I am still getting the same error using `BOOST_ROOT`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174875/discussion-between-lubgr-and-souki).

Answer (score 0):

Check if that boost_system library is installed in your host machine.

In Ubuntu 16.04 distro, you can do that with:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep libboost
```

And if not installed, you can install it with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install  libboost-system1.58  libboost-system1.58-dev
```

Comment: It is installed.

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_system means the linker can't find the boost_system installed in your host machine. Just for testing, export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/libboost_system and try again.

Comment: It does not change anything, unfortunatly.

Comment: Have you installed libboost in this path? /u/refdev64/boost/v1.66.0/ Because you are defining that path to seach for the library. Please, check content of that directory.